# Does a Backbone model id need to be numeric?

Tags: backbone.js

As the question asks, is it necessary to have a numeric (and presumably, integer) value for a model's id?  Or is any unique identifier acceptable?  For example, could I use a GUID string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can be any arbitrary string according to the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-id):

> ID
>
> A special property of models, the id is an arbitrary string (integer
> id or UUID). If you set the id in the attributes hash, it will be
> copied onto the model as a direct property. Models can be retrieved by
> id from collections, and the id is used to generate model URLs by
> default.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can. The [backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-id) states that "the id is an arbitrary string (integer id or UUID)".